# Google Sheets Script to Conditionally Format Cells in Rounds Using Random Number Generator

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, setvalue

I am attempting to create a virus-simulation in Google Sheets for a high school unit on exponential functions. I would like to set R0 and then simulate spread each day by running a script that:
-- reads a range of rows and columns (each cell simulates a person)
-- leaves the cell alone if it has already been infected (i.e., changed color)
-- randomly changes the color of the appropriate number of cells using a random number generator and the equation R0^N, where N is the number of days

This is my first script in Google Sheets, and it is frustrating. I am feeling the novice frustration. Below is my current iteration. Does anyone have suggestions

```
function ViralSpread() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("ModelingTransmission");
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("People");
  var values = range.getValues();
  i = 1;
  values.forEach(function(row) {
      j=1;
      row.forEach(function(col) {
      j++;
      var testrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,j);
      var testvalue = testrange.getValues();
      var newdata = [j];
      testvalue.setvalues(newdata);
      });
      i++;
 });
 }
```

Comment: Hi Kate! Thanks for explaining your problem. I would suggest you break down your problem into smaller chunks. It's much easier to find solutions to specific problems that other people have had rather than for a whole project.
Then explain what works and what doesn't. It's not clear form your question where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: I don't understand the big picture but at first sight you are getting 2 sheets where you only use "range" variable. What's the purpose of this? Keep in mind that `range.getValues()` will return a two-dimensional array of values instead of cells. As mentioned in the previous comment it'd be helpful for the community if you explained a little bit if this is throwing an error, where did you get stuck, among other things.